# Accessing a shared folder over a network in adobe air

Tags: air, adobe, unc, shared-directory

I'm trying to write to a shared folder on a windows network in AIR using the File class.  I don't understand how to format the path to the shared folder.  I get one of who errors with everything I've tried:  "The specified folder does not exist" and "there is a parameter missing".  The UNC path to access this folder from my computer is like this:

\\localdev01\platefiles

Here are the different path formats I've tried to access this folder:

\\localdev01\platefiles

/localdev01/platefiles

file://localdev01/platefiles (i get error #2 with this one)

file:///localdev01/platefiles

Does anyone have any guidance or suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure about \localdev01\platefiles ? There's normally two \s on a network path, ie, \\localdev01\platefiles

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, yeah, the UNC path is \\localdev01\platefiles

Answer (score 1):

for a shared directory like

```
\\localdev01\platefiles 

use

file:///\\localdev01\platefiles
```

Answer (score 0):

ex : for a shared directory from a pc with "pc-name"

```
file:////pc-name/folder/file.jpg
```