# as3 networked shares access

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

Hey relatively new to as3 is there already built in libraries that allow for connecting to remote shares that require authentication?

searching for as3 and smb is swarmed with results for a game written in flash called SMB, so i am not having any luck finding any info on google.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way that Flash Player can access samba/windows shared directories on local network due security sandbox that Flash Player runs in.

If you want Adobe Air to access UNC addresses on local network start with [Accessing a shared folder over a network in adobe air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182523/accessing-a-shared-folder-over-a-network-in-adobe-air)